# Number of 3-element subsets with only 1 common element

Tags: set-theory, combinations, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

In a party, there are $n$ guests attending where $3$ guests can seat around a table. What is the maximum number of ways in which they can be seated so that no $2$ guests sit together more than once?

**Method $1$**: This can be solved by considering a polygon with $n$ sides and connected diagonals (or a fully-connected graph with $n$ nodes) and determining the max. number of triangles possible with no common edge (or max. no. of $3$-edged cyclic paths such that there are no path overlaps). By doing this, I got the answer $n-3$, albeit not with a definite proof.

**Method $2$**: It can also be proved by finding all the $3$-element subsets of the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that intersection of any $2$ subsets will give an empty set or $1$-element set.

This is what I figured out as of now. But, I am unable to conclusively get an answer for both the methods. How to prove the results and solve for the original question with both of the above methods? Also, I am interested in knowing other interpretations of the problem other than Methods 1&2.

Answer (score 2):

**An upper bound**

Denote the integer part of a number $x$ by $\{x\}$.

Each guest can be seated in at most $\{\frac{n-1}{2}\}$ combinations. Then $n\{\frac{n-1}{2}\}$ counts each combination three times and so the maximum number of combinations is  $\{\frac{n\{\frac{n-1}{2}\}}{3}\}$.

**An example, $n=8$**

The above formula gives an upper bound of $8$. This can be attained since if we number the guests from $1$ to $8$, the following combinations can be made.

$123, 145, 167$

$825, 847, 863$

$246, 357$.

**The upper bound is attained if $n=6k+1$ or $6k+3$**

In this case the formula simplifies to $\frac {n(n-1)}{6}$ and T. Skolem has proved that this upper bound is always attained.

Reference - T. Skolem. Some remarks on the triple systems of Steiner. Math. Scand. 6 (1958), 273–280.

https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/10551

**The upper bound is attained if $n=6k$ or $6k+2$**

In this case the formula simplifies to $\frac {n(n-2)}{6}$ and the proof  that this can be attained  follows from  Skolem's solution for $n+1$ people.

This has $\frac {n(n+1)}{6}$ combinations and each person is in $\frac {n}{2}$ of them. The number of combinations not including a given person is therefore $$\frac {n(n+1)}{6}-\frac {n}{2}=\frac{n(n-2)}{6}.$$